# iPhone: Problems after application submission in AppStore

Tags: iphone, audio, gps, app-store, cllocationmanager

I've submitted my first iPhone App to the AppStore (on 10.09.10) and I have just found out that it was "Ready For Sale" (18.09.10). After a short moment of deep Happiness,  I've found out some problems in my App, that I DO NOT have when I install it on my iPhone using XCode:

1) My APP uses the CLLocationManager to get the GPS coordinates. I've already tested it and it works very well, but after downloading my App from AppStore, I've noticed that my App DOES NOT get any coordinates. Normally, after installing a new App on my iPhone, that needs to get the GPS coordinates, the iOS asks me if I want to allow that App to do so, but in the case with my App, the iOS does not ask me that question. Am I missing something?
P.S.: As I submitted my App to the Review-process I did NOT select the option which says that my App "needs the location services" (UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in my Info.plist). Do you think this was a mistake?

2) I have some "boolean buttons". When the user clicks on the button, it makes a sound. But in the AppStore version, it does not make ANY sound (even the sounds the picker makes when a picturen is taken can not be heard). Here is my method:

```
- (void) playMCSound:(BOOL)release {
    //Get the filename of the sound file:
    NSString *path;
    if (release) {
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                @"/releaseClick.wav"];            
    } else {
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                @"/cllick.wav"];            
    }

    //declare a system sound id
    SystemSoundID soundID;        
    //Get a URL for the sound file
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];        
    //Use audio sevices to create the sound
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);        
    //Use audio services to play the sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);        
}
```

Is something wrong with this method? (as I said: it works normally when I install the App using XCode)

My App is "KA Feedback", by the way. But it is only available in Germany.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to #1, check in the location services settings next to your app name, if location permission is "on" or "off", it's probably in the off position.

And for #2, while this may sound really silly, I have to ask that first, is the volume turned up when you're in say, the iPod app? I'm not talking about the ringer volume, but the volume of audio apps. Check that first. If it is indeed non-mute, then check in your distribution build, that releaseClick.wav (which is what I presume is supposed to be loaded) exists, and is being copied into the app bundle.

Comment: With respect to #1: YES. The location-service is activated to my App. As I submitted my App to the Review-process I did NOT select the option which says that my App "needs the location services". Do you think this was a mistake? Can I change this setting without putting the App into review again?

With respect to #2: I did not find any setting about "volume of audio apps" (I have an iPhone 4), but I am sure that the .wav files are in my bundle. I have them in my Resources-folder in XCode. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: You can try, I really don't know if that's something that has to go through review. With respect to audio, just open up the iPod app, and crank the volume. Exit iPod go into your app, and try and trigger the audio event. If you just crank the volume normally, it just adjusts the ringer volume, you need to adjust the audio playback volume.